# Show that the $\mathbb{B_v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3) $ is an ON-basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently studying som linear algebra and I stumbled on this problem:

The vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ has the coordinates $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)$, $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)$, $(0, 0, 1)$ in the standard base in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

**Show that the $\mathbb{B_v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3) $ is an ON-basis.**

Now this should be an easy enough problem:

Since we know that this is a base we simply have to check if the magnitude of the vectors are $1$. We do this by multiplying the vector with itself. So in the case above you simply multiply:

$v_1 \cdot v_1 =$ $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)$ $\cdot$ $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0) = 1$

From my understanding this would be equivalent to this:

$v_1 \cdot v_1 =$ $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)v_1$ $\cdot$ $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)v_1 = 1 |{v_1}^{2}|$

**What I am having a hard time to understand is how we can assert that $|{v_1}^{2}| = 1$. Since we don't know if the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are an ON-basis yet.**

The coordinates of $v_1$, $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)$, has to be expressed in some kind of base, and how do we know that that base is an ON-base?

I hope this was clear enough, thank you :)

Comment: You replace $v_1=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)v_1$ which is nonsense; the final $v_1$ should be left out. Correcting for that, you computed $v_1\cdot v_1=1$. The left hand side is $|v_1|^2$ (note the square is outside).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Makes sense, I suspected it was something wrong with writing it like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $v_2=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)$ is the same as writing $v_2=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot{\bf e}_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot{\bf e}_2+0\cdot{\bf e_3}$, where ${\bf e}_1=(1,0,0)$, ${\bf e}_2=(0,1,0)$ and ${\bf e}_3=(0,0,1)$. So $\langle v_2,v_2\rangle=\langle\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot{\bf e}_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot{\bf e}_2+0\cdot{\bf e_3},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot{\bf e}_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot{\bf e}_2+0\cdot{\bf e_3}\rangle={\rm since}\;{\bf e_i}$ is an ON-basis $=\frac{2}{4}\langle{\bf e}_1,{\bf e}_1\rangle+\frac{2}{4}\langle{\bf e}_2,{\bf e}_2\rangle+0\langle{\bf e}_3,{\bf e}_3\rangle=\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{4}=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex! Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome :). I appreciated your question too, it's one of that subtle things that we don't learn in classroom, and have to think about by ourselves...